# $f^{(n)}(x)$ exist $\forall x \in I$, an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ but $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ does not exist for any $x \in I$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

$f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, $f^{(3)}(x)$, ..., $f^{(n)}(x)$ all exist $\forall x \in I$, an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ but $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ does not exist for any $x \in I$

Can such a function exist?

In words: Does there exist a function $f$ that is $n$-times differentiable on an interval $I$ but is not $(n+1)$-times differentiable anywhere on $I$ (i.e. $(n+1)$-differentiable nowhere on $I$)?

I think it can't but can't think of the reason why. I can construct a function with countably infinite points in I where the function is only differentiable n times, but, it seems impossible to have every point in the interval, I, have this property.

Comment: Have you heard of  Weierstrass' nowhere differentiable, continuous function? (Integrate it.)

Comment: Yes.  Is there a way to smooth it out so it can be differentiated a finite number of times before failing at every point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Take the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) $f$. It is differentiable nowhere. If $F$ is a primitive of $f$ (which exists, since $f$ is continuous), then $F'$ exists, but $F''$ exists nowhere.

Comment: Does this same example disprove if I were to assume $f$ is continuously $n$-times differentiable instead of just $n$-times differentiable? this is my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275733/continuously-differentiable-on-an-interval-but-not-twice-differentiable-anywhere)

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Yes, it also works in that context.

Comment: Thanks José Carlos Santos! you can post answer there

Answer (score 2):

Take any continuous, nowhere differentiable function (e.g. Weierstrass function). Then integrate it $n$ times. 
First time you can do it, as the function is continuous. 
Later, you are integrating differentiable, so continuous, functions.

Comment: How do I know the first anti-derivative of the Weierstrass function is also continuous? I understand why I can integrate it once, but am still trying to understand doing it more than once.

Comment: The integral of a continuous function is differentiable, so is continuous and hence integrable.

Comment: If $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\;dt$, then $F'(x) = f(x)$ provided $f$ is continuous at the point $x$.  Perhaps your calculus textbook contains this fundamental theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar , Paweł Czyż , Does this same example disprove if I were to assume $f$ is continuously $n$-times differentiable instead of just $n$-times differentiable? this is my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275733/continuously-differentiable-on-an-interval-but-not-twice-differentiable-anywhere)