# Continuously/Differentiable on an interval but not twice differentiable anywhere in the/an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f: A \to \mathbb R$ be a function, where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ that contains an interval.

Of course there are examples where $f$ can be differentiable at a point $x \in A$ but not twice differentiable a point $x$. Now I want to ask about interval subsets of $A$.

There are [also examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414729/only-once-differentiable) $f$ is differentiable on an interval $I \subseteq A$ but not twice differentiable anywhere in $I$: Just do $I = A = \mathbb R$ and $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) dt$ where $g$ is Weierstrass.

1. (**Update**: Found it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742879/fnx-exist-forall-x-in-i-an-interval-in-mathbbr-but-fn1). This is the problem with not using words in your post...) To construct an example for that $f$ is $k$-times differentiable on $I$ but not $(k+1)$-times differentiable anywhere in $I$, for $k \ge 1$, can I just keep integrating $g$ recursively to get counterexamples? eg for $k=2$, $f(x) = \int_0^x \int_0^u g(t) dt du$
2. Can the same examples be used for when $f$ is instead continuously differentiable/continuous $k$-times differentiable on $I$?

Comment: Yes, those examples also show that there are functions $f$ such that $f^{(n)}$ exist and it is continuous, but also differentiable nowhere.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos as i said in another post: 1 - thanks 2 - you can post as answer

Comment: That's nice, but I don't want to post it as an answer, since I feel that I would be posting the same answer twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those examples also show that there are functions f such that f(n) exist and it is continuous, but also differentiable nowhere. –
José Carlos Santos